# What is a class constant?

Tags: java, class, constants, terminology

I am told to declare and initialize my class constant. I didn't know what it was so I searched google, apparently everyone already knows what it is and nobody has asked on it. So what is a class constant? Is it just a value that doesn't change throughout the class?

Comment: Plenty of Java tutorials, including Oracle's, should cover this.

Comment: @blm Yeah, it seemed like a basic thing it was just never mentioned in my class. Then I get a question about it which left me confused. It was something so basic that there wasn't even a definition when googled, lol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JLS-8.3.1.1. `static` Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) says (in part)

> A `static` field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized ([§12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)).

[JLS-4.12.4. `final` Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) says (in part)

> A *constant variable* is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28))

#### tl;dr

Putting that together, a class constant is a `static final` field.

Comment: if in my class we have not discussed `final`, I assume it is okay to use `public static type DEFAULT_NAME = "Bar";`?

Comment: If it's not `final` then it's not a **constant**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so isn’t that ‘public static final MyObject SOME_OBJECT = new MyObject();’ a constant?

Comment: @elvis Maybe. Where is that `public static final MyObject SOME_OBJECT = new MyObject();` and why are you asking in a comment on an **eight** year old question?

Answer (score 8):

Class variables are static; instance variables are not.

Final variables are constant.

So a class constant would be declared like this:

```
public class Foo {

    // Class constant 
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Bar";

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String name = Foo.DEFAULT_NAME;
    }
}
```

It's the same for all instances of `Foo`.